# PhpStorm does not recognize node.js syntax

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

I can't configure PhpStorm to work with NodeJs syntax, I've followed  [This](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+Started+with+Node.js+in+PhpStorm)
guide but for some reason it's not working - as you can see in the picture

[image]

Comment: Please verify that each step was followed carefully, and restart your IDE, your computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check what JS version is chosen in Preferences/Settings | Languages&Frameworks | JavaScript.

Arrow functions are supported only since ECMAScript 6.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Preferences/Settings | Languages&Frameworks | JavaScript.

Note that you should look in Settings and not Default settings.

Comment: Oksana - Thanks - i got it - turn out  ECMAScript 6 was installed by not defined - thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

yes i know it is late, but i thought maybe somebody land on this page & this might help.

first make sure node is installed using `node -v` command in terminal &
from *File* menu in phpstorm go to *Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM*

[image]

make sure **Coding assistance for Node.js** is checked like in the picture above (a package may get installed automatically)

& if it didn't work, try right click among codes of the file & from the big menu that appears (the menu i can't take screenshot of!) go to the last item *"Use JavaScript Library"* & from its submenu select *"Node.js Core"*

best regards :)